# I can't call javascript in angular

Tags: javascript, html

when i run this code in angular i get an error.

ERROR = Uncaught ReferenceError: openNav is not defined
at HTMLSpanElement.onclick ((index):14)

there is no error in the code because it works when ı type it like this onclick="document.getElementById('myNav').style.width = '0%'">×

I call it as <script src="my.js" /script> from outside but I still get the same error

I want to call the function from within the script, how can I do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<style>
  body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  }

  .overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }

  .overlay-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
  }

  .overlay a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }

  .overlay a:hover,
  .overlay a:focus {
    color: #f1f1f1;
  }

  .overlay .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 45px;
    font-size: 60px;
  }

  @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .overlay a {
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    .overlay .closebtn {
      font-size: 40px;
      top: 15px;
      right: 35px;
    }
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()"
    >&times;</a
  >
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Fullscreen Overlay Nav Example</h2>
<p>
  Click on the element below to open the fullscreen overlay navigation menu.
</p>
<p>
  In this example, the navigation menu will slide in, from left to right:
</p>
<span style="font-size: 30px; cursor: pointer" onclick="openNav()"
  >&#9776; open</span
>

<script>
  function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
  }

  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Angular separates html, js and css in a concept call Component. Why would you like to use angular, it seems not to make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: I write the function in my.js file, but I cannot call my.js in html, more precisely, it does not see the js codes.

Comment: You should get familiar with how Angular works. Read the basic tutorial first. If you want to use angular, you can't do the approach you are taking. If you want to take your approach, get rid of angular, that's also an option.